# how do I convert the characters of a mixed encoded file

Tags: php, python, parsing, text, character-encoding

I copied and pasted text from a PDF file but it didn't extract the numbers.  If I do less or more on the exported txt file I see the following:

```
"Christina, daughter of David Brodie, on <U+F735> November <U+F731><U+F736><U+F736><U+F735>. She was the sister of"
```

It should read:

> "Christina, daughter of David Brodie, on 5 November 1665. She was the sister of"

Initially I though it would be a simple search and replace, but the `<U+F73n>` numbers are encoded and I'm not sure how to extract them or even how they're encoded, although I did save the file as `utf-8` originally.  I tried to use php's `mb_string` functions to see if I could extract the codes in some way but I haven't been successful.

Has anyone else come across this problem and is there a simple solution that has eluded me?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f735/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately U+Fxxx is in the Private Use Area of Unicode. There is no automatic way to fix this, short of knowing the mapping ahead of time. Based on the codepoints in your sample, I would venture to say that you could subtract 0xF731 from the character values and then add 0x30 to convert them to ASCII numbers.

Comment: Thanks that set me on the right path.  I ended up reading the file byte by byte and replacing the offending bytes (3) with the correct ascii digit.